# Why there are 2 directories having same content?

Tags: command-line, filesystem, directory, proc

1. `cd /proc/$$/root/bin`
2. `cd /bin`

After running `ls` command on both the directory, I found that content of both directories are same (which is nothing but list of commands).

Is there any specific reason for this having same command-list in both directory?

Comment: nitpick: directories hold files (including *programs*), not commands. Commands are the strings that you give to shell, which in turn runs the appropriate programs or builtin functions.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`/proc` [is a "virtual" filesystem](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/proc.html) exposing some kernel and process related details.

`$$` is a [shell variable](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html) giving the PID of the shell running it.

`/proc/$$/root` is a [symbolic link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) to the root directory as seen by the current shell.
This could change in case you are [chrooting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot).

In short, the two look identical because they *are* the same directory. If you execute `ls -ld /proc/$$/root` you will see that it is a symbolic link to `/`, and therefore `/proc/$$/root/bin` and `/bin` are the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

That's because they are, in fact, the same directories¹:

```sh
$ test /proc/$$/root/bin -ef /bin; echo $?
0
```

(The `-ef` test checks whether two paths refer to the same file object.)

The same holds true for `/proc/$$/root` and `/`, because

```sh
$ readlink /proc/$$/root
/
```

¹ unless you are in a `chroot` environment which may point `/proc/$$/root` to a different directory.